# How can I find out whether I am permitted to re-use an online questionnaire in my own research?

Tags: research-undergraduate, copyright, online-resource, survey-research

So, I get this page's link: [User Interface Usability Evaluation with Web-Based Questionnaires](http://hcibib.org/perlman/question.html) from my friend. I want to make one of them as Questionnaire for the design I made for Academic Research. But I'm confused, is that only an example, a guideline, or can I use the Questionnaire as it is? Is there any license for those questionnaire? I've tried to read the page, but don't really know if there's something like that.

Answer (score 1):

The script doesn't seem to have a license but says, "question.cgi is a free script for administering user interface usability questionnaires on the web." In other places on the page you linked to, the authors encourage reuse. If you are unsure or unclear, you can contact the authors.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the text on the page is pretty clear:

> The script is freely available, AS-IS

So, yes, you can use it as it is.

Combine this with the (slightly) earlier text

> allows the online reader to design and create their own questionnaire

and I think there is only one way to interpret this as "Feel free to use this!"

Comment: I thought that statement only applied to the script, or source code, for showing those questionnaire. Like, maybe you want to make an online questionnaire, then you can use that script to show your questionnaire in your web. Hmmm or is the freely use of the script also meant the freely use of the questionnaire 's contents too? Does the script also include the questionnaire's contents too?